# Compilation error in lex program with yy_scan_string on IBM machine

Tags: lex

My program works fine on a Linux machine but when I compile on an IBM `yy_scan_string` doesn't work. Do I need to declare or define `yy_scan_string`?

```
 File : "file.l"

 %{

 #nclude <iostream>

 #include <cstring>

 bool st = false;
 %}

 %%

  .([.][fF][1-9][0-9][Kk])$ { st = true; }

  . { st = false; }

  %%

  int main()

  {

      const char *fName = "check.f9k";

      char *elem = new char[strlen(fName) + 1];

      sprintf(elem, "%s\n", fName);

      yy_scan_string(elem);
      yylex();

      std::cout<<"\n ST : "<<st<<"\n";
      return 0;
  }

  int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

Compile :

```
lex file.l

g++ -o outfile lex.yy.c -ll

lex.yy.c: In function 'int main()': lex.yy.c:131: error: 'yy_scan_string' was not declared in this scope
```

How can I resolve this error on my IBM machine?

Answer (score 1):

`yy_scan_string` is part of `flex`, but it is not part of traditional `lex`. I presume that your "IBM machine" has AT&T lex installed. (It might have `flex` as well.)